# Allow remote connections on SQL Server 2012 Express ..

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I need to allow remote connections in SQL Server 2012 Express, the problem is that I am following every tutorial but without luck. The Microsoft tutorial and every one that I have been reading have sections that I don't have in my SQL Server Configuration Manager.

The msdn tutorial says this:

> In SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the console pane, expand SQL Server Network Configuration, expand Protocols for , and then double-click TCP/IP.
>
> In the TCP/IP Properties dialog box, on the IP Addresses tab, several IP addresses appear in the format IP1, IP2, up to IPAll. One of these is for the IP address of the loopback adapter, 127.0.0.1. Additional IP addresses appear for each IP Address on the computer. Right-click each address, and then click Properties to identify the IP address that you want to configure.
>
> If the TCP Dynamic Ports dialog box contains 0, indicating the Database Engine is listening on dynamic ports, delete the 0.
>
> In the IPn Properties area box, in the TCP Port box, type the port number you want this IP address to listen on, and then click OK.
>
> In the console pane, click SQL Server Services.
>
> In the details pane, right-click SQL Server () and then click Restart, to stop and restart SQL Server.

I don't have a SQL Network Configuration and the data I have is not the same.

This is how is my configuration right now (I don't know why says SQL Server 2005 Services, it does have anything in that section).

[image]

This is what I have installed on my pc (Windows 8.1 x64)

[image]

Comment: Hm, `expand SQL Server Network Configuration` and yet you are in `SQL Native Client Configuration`...?

Comment: Did you open the *right* SQL Server Configuration Manager? It seems you do have SQL Server 2005 installed - did you by accident open the **2005** configuration manager?

Comment: I dont have a section called SQL Server Network Configuration, only a SQL Server 2005 Network Configuration and it does not have any child items

Comment: I dont know where is the 2012 SQL Server Configuration Manager.. this is the only one that windows has found

Comment: Start Menu > All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server *2012* > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally thanks to `@marc_s` i founded that the SQL Server Configuration Manager was 2005 version and the 2012 version was not in start menu, so i searched manually and got it working now.